# Is this function measurable? Something to do with Bochner space and norms.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f:[0,T]\to X$ is a measurable map where $X$ is Hilbert space. Suppose also that $R(t):X \to X^*$ is an isometric isomorphism with
$$\lVert R(t)f(t)\rVert_{X^*} = \lVert f(t) \rVert_X$$
also measurable.

Can we deduce
$$t \mapsto R(t)f(t)$$ is measurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as $R(t)$ is otherwise arbitrary, the answer is no. Take a non-measurable set $E$ and put
$$
R(t) = \begin{cases}R&t \in E\\-R & t \not\in E\end{cases}
$$
for some isometric isomorphism $R$. Together with a constant $f$, this yields a non-measurable $R(t)\,f(t)$.